# Reinitialising an array on if statement

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing class that manages dynamic array of objects. Right now I got stuck on method that should insert element at given index, but before it checks if that index isnt bigger than array capacity. Then it should resize array first.

```
template <class T>
void MyVector<T>::insertAt(int index, const T &m_element) {
    if(p_size == p_capacity) extendArray();
    if(index >= p_capacity) extendArray(index);
    p_size++;
    p_array[index] = m_element; 
}

    template <class T>
void MyVector<T>::extendArray(int new_capacity) {    
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> temp_array = std::make_unique<T[]>(new_capacity);
    for (int i = 0; i <= p_size; i++) {
        temp_array[i] = p_array[i];
    }

    p_array.reset();

    p_array = std::make_unique<T[]>(new_capacity);
    for (int i = 0; i <= p_size; i++) {
        p_array[i] = temp_array[i];
    }  
}
```

extendArray()just extends array capacity 2 times, extendArray(int) extends array capacity to the number given by the index. First method works fine, second not so really.

```
int main(){
    MyVector<int> test;
    test.insertAt(0, 5);
    test.insertAt(1, 3);
    test.insertAt(2, 1);
    test.insertAt(6, 11);   

    cout <<"Size " << test.getSize() << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < test.getCapacity(); i++) {
        cout << test.get(i) << ", ";
    }
}
```

Id expect something like 5, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0
But I get just 5, 3, 1, 0 so it never extends array but it increases size (number of elements).

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= p_size...` A `for` loop using `<=` raises red flags.  Those red flags being off-by-one errors.  And why are you writing your own class instead of using `std::vector`?

Comment: `if(index >= p_capacity) extendArray(index);` Say you have 2 element array, index 0 and 1. You want to add something on index 2. You pass this index as new size and end up with .... the same 2 element array. What is the catch?

Comment: Yeah corrected that for loops. I'm just learning stuff, thought that making my own class that works similar to std::vector would teach me a bit. Constructor makes p_capacity = 2. If I want to insert something at index 4 it doesn't exists (index > capacity). Thats why I want to resize my array first to the capacity that can contain given index.

Comment: Well, new array size/capacity isn's equals to index, it equals to index + 1, to prevent what you suggested. Still, it doesn't fix my problem, extendArray() without parameters extends array two times when needed (after pushBack for example), but extendArray(int) doesn't work, while it is basicly copy/paste function.

Comment: I imagine you probably meant to update `p_capacity` to reflect the new capacity somewhere in `extendArray`. As far as I can tell you aren't doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your `extendArray()` function but even though you say it's a copy of `extendArray(int)` first seems to be updating p_capacity when the latter you provided doesn't.

Fixing that would gain you couple of extra zeros in the output `5, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0` since you extending only to the index, not to the `index+1`. Furthermore, in `insertAt(int index, const T &m_element)` you are incrementing the `p_size`, instead of assigning it to `index+1`

Extending to `p_size+1` and fixing the `p_size` assignment, prints [5, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 11](http://cpp.sh/6tgg) and I am not quite sure how you came to the conclusion that it should have an extra trailing 0 as `p_capacity` ends up being 7, regardless if the initial value is 1, 2 or 4 as in the code snippet I put a link to.

I also noticed couple of bugs I  without looking too close: your loops shouldn't go to the `p_size`, but rather to `p_size-1`, so instead `for (size_t i = 0; i <= p_size; i++)` it should be `for (size_t i = 0; i < p_size; i++)`

I would also suggest using unsigned int (or size_t) instead of int for indexing as that allows to get compiler warnings when you do something which potentially can result in a negative index.

Lastly, you should be able to use [unique_ptr::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/swap/) to avoid two allocations in extendArray(..).

Good luck with learning!